# Is there a multilinear principal component regression?

Tags: regression, pca, tensor

[PCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_regression) is a linear regression problem on top of [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

Analogically, is there a 'multilinear PCR' as a linear or multilinear regression problem (e.g. [CP tensor regression](http://tensorly.org/stable/auto_examples/regression/plot_cp_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-regression-plot-cp-regression-py) and [Tucker tensor regression](http://tensorly.org/stable/auto_examples/regression/plot_tucker_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-regression-plot-tucker-regression-py) for examples) on top of [MPCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_principal_component_analysis)?

Comment: Related: [What is multilinear principal components analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588109/what-is-multilinear-principal-components-analysis)?