# Is there a multilinear kernel principal components analysis?

Tags: pca, kernel-trick, tensor

[PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) can be extended to [kPCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_principal_component_analysis) using the [kernel trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method).

[MPCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_principal_component_analysis) is a multilinear extension of PCA that involves multiple matrices for the different modes of the data tensor.

Can MCPA be similarly extended using the kernel trick?

Comment: Related: [What is multilinear principal components analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588109/what-is-multilinear-principal-components-analysis)?